# Allow reading of multiple XMLfile names from folder using SQL code

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sqlbulkcopy, openrowset

I have a created a stored procedure that functions fine with a hard coded XML file name. However I cannot keep hard coding the file name as every time a new file comes in it will have a different file name although the XML structure remains the same.

I wondered if anyone could help/point me in the right direction. Here is my code that works with the hard coded xml file name. Now I need it to read all the XML files that exist in the C:\temp\ folder and not just one.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[XMLIputData] as 

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.sxi.co.za/XMLSchema')

INSERT INTO FNBXMLData 
    (  
        [CIpriority],
        [ref_num],
        [summary],
        [act_log],
        [impact.sym],
        [category.sym],
        [affected_resource.name],
        [affected_resource.class.type],
        [status.sym],
        [customer.billing_code.name], 
        [affected_resource.model.sym],
        [customer.first_name],
        [customer.last_name],
        [customer.phone_number],
        [customer.beeper_phone] ,
        [customer.email_address] ,
        [location.name] ,
        [affected_resource.location.address1] ,
        [affected_resource.location.address6] ,
        [affected_resource.location.city.sym] ,
        [affected_resource.location.state.sym] ,
        [category.service_type.sys] ,
        [affected_resource.znr_inc_service_type.sym] ,
        [affected_resource.znr_cr_service_type.sym] ,
        [category.service.type.sym] ,
        [SXI_SigReg_ActionField] ,
        [SXI_SigReg_EntryIdField] ,
        [SXI_SigReg_EpochTimeField] ,
        [SXI_SigReg_UniqueIdField]) 
SELECT  
        X.product.query('CIpriority').value('.', 'varchar(5)'),
        X.product.query('ref_num').value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
        X.product.query('summary').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('act_log').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('impact.sym').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('category.sym').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.name').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.class.type').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('status.sym').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),
        X.product.query('customer.billing_code.name').value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.model.sym').value('.', 'varchar(50)'),
        X.product.query('customer.first_name').value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
        X.product.query('customer.last_name').value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
        X.product.query('customer.phone_number').value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
        X.product.query('customer.beeper_phone').value('.', 'varchar(20)'),
        X.product.query('customer.email_address').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('location.name').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.location.address1').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.location.address6').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.location.city.sym').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.location.state.sym').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('category.service_type.sys').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.znr_inc_service_type.sym').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('affected_resource.znr_cr_service_type.sym').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('category.service.type.sym').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('SXI_SigReg_ActionField').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('SXI_SigReg_EntryIdField').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('SXI_SigReg_EpochTimeField').value('.', 'varchar(200)'),
        X.product.query('SXI_SigReg_UniqueIdField').value('.', 'varchar(200)')

FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'C:\temp\X-ServiceBroker~FNBUSD-DIEBOLD~702012850747092.75.xml',
     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
     ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('XServiceBroker') AS X(product);
GO
```

Comment: Btw: It should be enough to shorten this `X.product.query('location.name').value('.', 'varchar(200)')` to this `X.product.value('(location.name)[1]', 'varchar(200)')`. This combination of `.query()` and `.value()` is often to be found, but not really needed...

Comment: Hi yes it is, sorry I was sick yesterday had to be in hospital. I am however back at it today... Let me try this solution and I will update. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You might try it like this

```
--You need a table to insert into
CREATE TABLE dbo.XmlTarget(MyXML XML);

--this is the dynamically changing filename
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(250) =N'X:\PathToFile\TestXml.xml';

--this is a dynamic command to allow a changing filename
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
'INSERT INTO dbo.XmlTarget(MyXML)
 SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
 FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK ''' +  @FileName + ''',SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x);'

--execute the statement
EXEC (@cmd);

--Now the XML is in the table
SELECT * FROM dbo.XmlTarget;

--CleanUp
DROP TABLE dbo.XmlTarget;
```

Comment: Okay sorry I am a bit confused, I am not familiar with this... in the section where I declare the @FileName variable, since I will not know the xml file name and will only know the path to where the xml files reside will TestXml.xml work for any xml?

Comment: Ok I have tried this and it returns as a result the xml file and names it MyXML. I think I need to explain further on what I am trying to do. 

I already have a table to save the data that will be in the xml file and this is successful and the table gets populated with the xml information inside the tags as desired..

My problem right now is I do not want to hard code the xml file name, as I need to be able to read all the xml files that come into that folder on the C drive.

Comment: @Zonke I just re-read your question... Is the table you are talking about the table of your Stored Procedure? Are the files always and in any future the same structure? I'd advise to read the XML into a single columm of type XML first (this works with any valid XML) and then continue from there. But maybe I've got something wrong...